# Moving SharePoint subsite to root of site collection using Deployment API

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We are in the process of restructuring our SharePoint environment and have subsites that we will be migrating to their own site collection. However we need to preserve the GUIDs of objects as we do this, so we will be using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment` option.

The trouble I'm running in to is that using this won't allow me to import an exported web into the root of a new site collection. It keeps the subweb path

For example, if I export a web such as this

```
Export-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/site1/example" -Path c:\export\example.cmp
```

Then import it with the following script

```
$siteURL = "http://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/site2/"
$fileLocation = "c:\export"
$fileName = "example.cmp"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::load("Microsoft.Sharepoint, version=12.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=71e9bce111e9429c")

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment")

# settings

$settings = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportSettings
$settings.SiteUrl = $siteURL
$settings.WebUrl = $siteURL
$settings.FileLocation = $fileLocation
$settings.FileCompression = $true
$settings.RetainObjectIdentity = $true
$settings.UserInfoDateTime = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportUserInfoDateTimeOption]::ImportAll
$settings.BaseFileName = $fileName

$import = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport($settings)
$import.Run()
```

The intent is that *example.cmp* will restore to `http://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/site2/` as the root web, however this restores to `http://sharepoint.domain.com/sites/site2/example`

Does anyone know how to get this to restore to the root? I can't use `Import-SPWeb` to do this because I need to preserve the GUIDs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to preserve the GUIDs?

Comment: Mostly to prevent us from needing to recreate workflows associated to lists. Trying to not need to recreate them all, they continue to function fine using `SPImport`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research into this, since the site we are trying to move to its own site collection has Publishing enabled, it appears to be required to be done this way anyway.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/968483

> Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007/2010/2013 does not support
>   migrations of subsites into root sites or root sites into subsites in
>   site collections that have the Publishing features turned on.

I'm guessing the Deployment API is using this limitation in mind.

For reference, this is the resolution to this which we will need to follow.

> Valid migration scenarios when using the Publishing features are the
>   following:
>
> - Export the site collection starting at the root site and then import it as the root site into a new site collection
> - Export subsites of the site collection and then import them as subsites into an existing site collection that has the Publishing
>     features enabled